# Solution for MacBook Pro "Service Battery" Warning

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, battery, macbook-pro

Have you any experience with the Service Battery warning in MacBook pro? It has been reported in manu forums that an upgrade to Mac OS X Snow Leopard causes the battery to indicate Service Battery Warning. I've resetted SMC controller and the problem disappeared for a while but again after a few days it reappeared. I do not have access to apple support and links to apple support page are not helpful, as it is reported by many users that use that forum.

Do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Reset SMC controller](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964), as you've done.
   <sup>*If this fails, continue.*</sup>
2. [Recalibrate battery.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490)
   <sup>*If this fails, continue.*</sup>
3. [Buy a battery](http://www.batteryeshop.com/laptop-battery/apple/) from someone other than Sony.
   <sup>*If this fails, continue.*</sup>
4. Get Apple to replace it.

Comment: Apple authorized service partners have a tool that can analyze your battery more thoroughly and can see what's wrong. Depending on the age of your Mac and the issue, you might even get a free replacement.

Comment: why specifically not sony?